# Failed to share a file with share_plus 4.0.5 on android 11

Tags: flutter, share-plus

failed to share a file with share_plus 4.0.5 on android 11

this is the code:

```
            await Share.shareFiles(  
                [ pdfFile.path ],
                text: 'Notes'
            );
```

For example, by sharing
google drive, the answer is: cannot schedule a file upload

Only the text is received by the apps where it is shared,
but the file is not.

when sharing with some apps the following message appears:

Permission Denial: opening provider dev.fluttercommunity.plus.share.ShareFileProvider from ProcessRecord{64aac...plore/uoa270}(uid=10270) thath is not exported from UID 10390

the file is notes.pdf and I put it in the 'Temp' folder in the app's temporary storage, which I get with
getTemporaryDirectory()
and what I try to share is
/data/user/0/com.example.app1/cache/Temp/notas.pdf

Also, in the AndroidManifest.xml file
I add these lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <!-- android 10    api 29 -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
        <!-- android 11    api 30 -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

also:
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

and:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" /> 
    </provider>
```

Comment: What is the path of the file? Does the application have permissions to access it?

Comment: the file is notes.pdf and I put it in the 'Temp' folder in the app's temporary storage, which I get with
getTemporaryDirectory()
and what I try to share is
/data/user/0/com.example.app1/cache/Temp/notas.pdf

Comment: the problem was in my cell phone

I already resolved it

Comment: i have same problem, can you tell how to resolve it?